# how to print mulidimensional array?

Tags: php, javascript, json

```
$list=array('Andaman and Nicobar'=>array( 'North and Middle Andaman', 'South Andaman', 'Nicobar' ), 'Andhra Pradesh' => array( 'Adilabad', 'Anantapur',));
```

in form of

```
[['North and Middle Andaman', 'South Andaman', 'Nicobar'],['Adilabad', 'Anantapur']]
```

Comment: So you're asking how to get PHP to output a JSON representation of that nested array? Why the JavaScript tag?

Answer (score 6):

```
$tmp = json_encode($list);
echo $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print multidimensional array by php
a simple example here...

```
<?php
    $company = array(
        array('company','HCL', 'Microsoft','apple'),
        array('city ','Delhi','California','Newyork'),
        array('Type','IT','Software','Iphone')
    );
    ?>
    <table border="1">

    <?php
    foreach($company as $data)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($data as $item)
        {
            echo "<td>$item</td>";


      }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Dont say thanx to me... :))